# Parameters that can be passed while opening CPLEX

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

When invoking cplex from the command line, I can provide a filename that contains a set of commands:

```
cplex -f filename
```

Is there a place which has a list of all commands that can be supplied while invoking CPLEX? I keep finding commands that can be given after opening CPLEX.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you are running interactive CPLEX.  The list of commands is available from [ibm](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/InteractiveOptimizer/topics/commands.html).  You can also type cplex to get to the interactive prompt.  From there, you can type [help](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/tutorials/InteractiveOptimizer/helpCmd.html) to get a list of commands.

Comment: Thanks. These are commands that I can use after I type cplex and interactive cplex starts. But I can provide certain arguments while starting interactive cplex, not after it. For example, the filename that contains commands that should be executed. Where do I find these arguments? The ones that can be provided while invoking cplex, not after it is invoked. I mean, how do I know what -f means in that command? Or what are the other options that can be given?

Comment: the only command line options that I know are are "-f and -c".  What others have you learned about?